# S3 Bucket Policy to grant ListBucket permission to all users of a different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have an Amazon S3 bucket in Account A.

I would like to grant `ListBucket` permission on this bucket to all users in Account B.

I tried to write an S3 Bucket Policy using a `Principal` of:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<account_b>:user/*"
},
```

But I get an error:

```
Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Invalid principal in policy
```

Is there a way that I can grant this permission?

Comment: Where are you trying to set this? You cannot use the Principal element in an identity-based policy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i guess i should of been more clear this is the policy on an S3 bucket, i just want to give ListObjects permission to all users on an external account for example since they keep making new users

Comment: I re-wrote your question to be a little clearer, hopefully I got it right. Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: awesome that's exactly it thanks @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When giving access to users in the other account, it's enough that you put just the account number as the principal:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS":"<account_b_number>"
},
```

It is also required that users in account b have access to the bucket defined in their IAM policy.

Comment: Thanks! That was simple enough on a side note AWS auto converted the above for me to `arn:aws:iam::<account_b_number>:root`

Comment: Yeah, those are 2 ways you can write it :)